# unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const" when linking to a shared Q_OBJECT

Tags: qt, cmake

I want to make two QObject libraries using cmake on windows: ProA & ProB, where ProB depend on ProA.

The code of ProA looks like:

```
class ProA_Export ProA: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...
};
```

The ProB links ProA in CMake: `target_link_libraries(ProB ProA)`.

Then, when I `#include "ProA.h"` in ProB, it reproted:

```
unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const ProA::staticMetaObject"
```

If I remove the `Q_OBJECT` from ProA, everything is OK except that the signal-slot of QT do not work.

So, how can I solve the `unresolved external symbol` problem caused by `Q_OBJECT`?

Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

--------------------- update --------------------

Finally, I find that it is `connect` cause the problem.

I change

```
connect(m_combobox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(indexChangeSlot(int)));
```

to

```
connect(m_combobox, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this, &ProA::indexChangeSlot)
```

Then, everything is OK. In addition, I find `Q_OBJECT` is not necessary.

Hope it can help somebody.

Comment: Probably the corresponding `moc_*` file is not generated. You might try to add `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` to your cmake script.

Comment: Which operating system? Dynamic, or static libraries?

Comment: @vahancho, @Wisblade, thank you for your kindly reply. The operating system is win10, and I want to generate dynamic library. @vahancho, I have add set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) in my cmake script. And, I can seee mocs_compilation_Debug.cpp in the vs, and the content of mocs_compilation_Debug is #include <EWIEGA46WW/moc_ProA.cpp>. I also find `moc_ProA.cpp` in `build\autogen\include_Debug\EWIEGA46WW\moc_ProA.cpp`